# Fedora package manager GUI vanished

Tags: linux, fedora, package-management

I upgraded Fedora from 19 to 20. Now I cannot find the package manager GUI. I reinstalled PackageKit and gnome-packagekit -- no effect.

How do I fix this?

Comment: When you write "cannot find", does that mean it is not present, can't be executed, and/or can't be found in graphical (Gnome) menu?

Comment: It is not under the Gnome menu, and either it is gone or I don't know how to find it from the terminal.

Comment: Oops - was looking for wrong package under yum!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sudo yum install gnome-software.x86_64` fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

open terminal

*su -*

*yum install yumex*

Comment: This is different than the default package manager GUI on Fedora 18 and 19.

Answer (score 0):

To solve it, run (as root):

`# yum install gnome-packagekit-installer`